# TelegramBot python. Request Location при нажатии на inline button

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Хочу запросить локацию при нажатии инлайн баттона, не знаю как

```
def options(bot, update):
    query = update.callback_query
    chat_id = query.message.chat_id
    option = str(query.data)
    text = ""

    if option == "wakeup":
        #Надо запросить локацию клиента и получить в этой функции
        #И обработать локацию в зависимости от опции(query.data)
        pass
    bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=query.message.chat_id,
                          message_id=query.message.message_id,
                          text=str(option),
                          reply_markup=first_menu_keyboard())

def first_menu_keyboard():
    keyboard = [[InlineKeyboardButton('#wakeup', callback_data='wakeup')],
                [InlineKeyboardButton('#reading', callback_data='reading')],
                [InlineKeyboardButton('#exercise', callback_data='exercise')]]
    return InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)

dispatcher.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(options, pattern='wakeup'))
dispatcher.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(options, pattern='reading'))
dispatcher.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(options, pattern='exercise'))
```